# Spring not using existing session

Tags: java, spring

Part1 of the webapp creates session1, and use session1 through those pages. When we call another sub part of the app, ex: part0.5, it still uses session1, and comes back with session1 to part1.

Then, the webapp goes into another part, part2, permanently leaving part1, still with session1. In part2 of the webapp, as soon as we call another part of the app, ex part0.5, it uses a new session, session2. When it comes back to part2, its back on session1. As soon as it leaves for another part, part0.5,part 0.6, or even part 1, it is again with session2.

However, if we leave part2 and gives the jsessionid of session1, they DO arrive with session1 on part 0.5, 0.6, 1...

We're using Spring and everything scoped to prototype.

Comment: without specifics, it's hard to know why it works for part1 and part0.5 but not for part2

Comment: Are these parts in the same web application and application context?

Comment: @Luiggi yes they are